# Applescript does not work when using macscript() in office, but it does when I paste into the script editor?

Tags: excel, macos, shell, applescript

Here is my code:

```
nameFilter = "'.*/([^~][^/]*" & nameFilter & "[^/]*|" & nameFilter & "[^/]*)\\.(xls|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb)$' "

scriptToRun = "do shell script """ & "find -E " & folderPath & " -iregex " & nameFilter & "-maxdepth 1 ! -iname '*Personal*'" & """ "

invoicesToAddToList = MacScript(scriptToRun)
MsgBox scriptToRun
MsgBox invoicesToAddToList
```

The first MsgBox looks like this:

[image: picture]

The second MsgBox displays blank, as if nothing was returned from MacScript()

What is crazy is that I can copy and paste the text from that Message Box into an Apple Script editor, and it returns a file every time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what was happening.  (Well, sort of..)
I have to call "macscript("choose folder as string")" and then select a folder that is a root to the folders I will be working with in order to return any filenames.  If someone could explain THAT to me, that would be great :D

Comment: I figured this out, as well!  Excel's developers were required to sandbox the program, which is what was giving me trouble.